What language has a small difference between word length of advanced VS basic vocabulary?
word length on Swadesh list
Zipf's Law
Basic vocabulary is used more frequently and the word length (#syllables/#segments) is generally shorter than advanced/technical/formal vocabulary.
In English:
teach VS educate, sound VS acoustics, money VS capital, thought VS consideration...
As many advanced words come from Greek/ Latin and they usually have longer roots than Germanic roots.
In Chinese:
jiao4 VS jiao4 yu4, sheng1 yin1 VS sheng1 xue2, (jin1) qian2 VS zi1 jin1, xiang2 fa3 VS kao3 liang4...
Most words are disyllabic. Many words have elastic length (monosyllabic or disyllabic). The difference in length between advanced VS basic words is much smaller than English. (Advanced words are mostly built on monosyllabic Chinese roots)
In basic vocabulary, English (monosyllabic) maybe a bit shorter than Chinese (disyllabic).
Eg. when? - shen2 me shi2 hou4,
bank - yin2 hang2,
should - ying1 gai1
But in advanced vocabulary, Chinese is way shorter than the full English form. Chinese stays disyllabic while English words become long:
Eg. Federal Bureau of Investigation (FBI) - lian2 bang1 diao4 cha2 ju2 (lian2 bang1 ju2/ mei3 lian2 ju2),
Department of Education (jiao4 yu4 ju2)
In Japanese (and probably Korean):
kudamono VS kajitsu, oto VS onkyou, okane VS shihon, nigeru VS touhi, sakana VS gyokai...
Honorific speech is very verbose in Japanese but formal/advanced words (mostly built on Chinese roots) do not have lots of #morae (because of the disyllabic nature of Chinese loanwords). They are sometimes even shorter than basic words of native roots in terms of #character and #syllables.
In Arabic/Hebrew:
I wonder if the dominance of triconsonantal roots makes the difference between length of advanced VS basic vocabulary very small.
Besides these languages, which languages have a comparatively small difference between length of advanced VS basic vocabulary?
